# Scala No Method Found Exception

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am using getting the below line of error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.wrapRefArray(java.lang.Object[])'
```

My Pom :

```
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any help regarding this ?

Comment: Looks like you're mixing Scala versions somewhere. Everything on the class path must be all 2.11, or all 2.12, or all 2.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `mvn dependency:tree`.

All your Scala libs will be suffixed with the major Scala version:

```
[INFO] +- io.circe:circe-config_2.12:jar:0.6.1:compile <-- scala 2.12 lib
[INFO] |  +- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.circe:circe-parser_2.12:jar:0.11.1:compile <-- scala 2.12 lib
```

All of them need to be the same major version otherwise you'll get binary incompatible libs at runtime.

Your maven pom should have all Scala libs suffixed to the same version like this:

```
<artifactId>circe-config_2.12</artifactId>
```

and of course the Scala maven plugin aligned with the same version.